# What is the rationale behind std::optional?

Tags: c++, std, option-type

To me, `std::optional<T>` always was a "cleaner" version of `std::unique_ptr<T>`: both have an empty state (`optional()` and `nullptr`) and own a `T` object otherwise. This analogy, however, breaks down when considering `std::optional<const T>`. The first code block is valid, while the second one should not be, as the type (`const T`) needs to be MoveAssignable.

```
std::unique_ptr<const int> ptr1, ptr2;
ptr1 = std::move(ptr2);

std::optional<const int> opt1, opt2;
opt1 = std::move(opt2);
```

With a similar reasoning, I would expect `std::optional<T&>` to be equivalent to a non-owning pointer `T*`. While this analogy is a bit blurry for general `T`, I think it would make much sense for `const T`.

```
const int ZERO = 0;

void AssignPtrIfNull(const int*& ptr) {
  ptr = (ptr == nullptr ? &ZERO : ptr);
}

void AssignOptIfNull(std::optional<const int&>& ptr) {
  ptr = (ptr ? make_optional<const int&>(ZERO) : ptr);
}
```

So I am wondering, what is the thought process behind making `optional` the way it is? Because it seems really odd to me. Are there some pitfalls I am overseeing?

Comment: Why are you comparing `std::optional` with `std::unique_ptr` as they are different beasts?

Comment: Rationale can be found by reading about `std::optional`'s ancestor [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). They are quite close in spirit, despite the standard type having some small changes.

Comment: @EdHeal I thought I made my comparison clear; what part do you not understand? Of course they are different but optional always felt to me like a modern version of the "pass null as empty object" paradigm.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, I will have a look to see if that clarifies the issue for me.

Comment: One is to do with pointers - the other is not

Comment: @EdHeal And pointers have been and are still often used when actually an optional is meant, so I don't think the comparison is far-fetched.

Comment: How about having the uniqueness in unique_ptr? (Re: different to shared_ptr)

Comment: @AndreasT: "*And pointers have been and are still often used when actually an optional is meant, so I don't think the comparison is far-fetched.*" But that depends on what the *caller* has. If the caller already has a `T`, they shouldn't have to wrap it up in an `optional` just to call your function; that just needlessly wastes performance. Also, `std::optional<T&>` isn't legal in C++17, so it's not clear what you're talking about.

Comment: @EdHeal I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: A pointer you can have multiple copies of. A shared pointer you can also have multiple copies of them - but when the last person drops it, the data gets deleted. Unique pointer means there is only one copy at most. Cannot be shared

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't see how that relates to my point. I was asking about the rationale behind the design choices of optional. You apparently want to discuss my comments in which I only explain to Ed Heal what the connection between optional and pointers is.

Comment: @EdHeal `unique_ptr<int>` contains the only copy of an int and `optional<int>` contains the only copy of an int. optional seems much closer unique_ptr than shared_ptr.

Comment: @AndreasT: "*I don't see how that relates to my point.*" It relates to your point by showing that your reasoning about what `optional` means leads to bad interfaces. And that your question contains ill-formed code, which is partially at the root of your misconceptions about what `optional` is.

Comment: No it does not - `unique_ptr<int>` - stores a pointer to an int. `optional<int>` does not store a pointer to an int

Comment: @EdHeal You are obviously not trying to help but only want to argue semantics and formulations so I don't see any point in pursuing this conversation any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything in the c++ standard library post c++11, `std::optional` was lifted straight out of the `boost` library suite.

The motivation is laid out [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/optional/tutorial.html#boost_optional.tutorial.motivation)